# Equivalent of java `TreeMap.lowerEntry` and `TreeMap.higherEntry` in C++ map?

Tags: java, c++

I think `C++` std::`map.lower_bound` equals to java's `TreeMap.higherEntry`.
What is the equivalent of java's `TreeMap.lowerEntry` in `C++` std::map?

Comment: I.e. like `map::upper_bound()`? Gives you an iterator that points to the (potentially abstract) location *after* the supplied key. Will return `map::end()` if there is no such entry in the map.

Comment: Actually, `upper_bound` is equivalent to `higherEntry`, not `lower_bound`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of both C++ functions is a bidirectional iterator. So, you can do this:

```
lowerEntry = --mymap.lower_bound(mykey);
```

Of course, you can only do this if `mymap.lower_bound(mykey) != mymap.begin()`.

Note that it is crucial that you use `lower_bound` and not `upper_bound`. If you use `upper_bound`, you may or may not end up with a pair that has key equal to `mykey`.

Wrapped in a function:

```
template < typename Key, typename Value, typename Compare, typename Alloc >
auto lowerEntry(std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Alloc>& map, Key key) -> decltype(map.begin()) {
    auto iter = map.lower_bound(key); // find the first element to go at or after key
    if(iter == map.begin()) // all elements go after key
        return map.end(); // signals that no lowerEntry could be found
    return --iter; // pre-decrement to return an iterator to the element before iter
}
```

Don't mind all the template stuff - it's rather awkward.

The trailing return type (`-> decltype(...)`) is just to make the function signature a little more readable. If you don't have access to C++11, then you can use this as the signature instead:

```
typename std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Alloc>::iterator lowerEntry(std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Alloc>& map, Key key) {
```

Here's a link to a code snippet on Wandbox (which allows you to run it in several compilers): http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/slFyTXHgFzWiZEIL

Comment: It is still not correct. For example, `std::map<int, string> mymap; mymap[10] = "hi";`, then both `mymap.lower_bound(11)` and `mymap.lower_bound(11)--' are NULL. `mymap.upper_bound(11) is also NULL`. But for Java, `TreeMap<Integer, String> mymap1 = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(); mymap1.put(10, "hi");`,  `mymap1.lowerEntry(11)` will return "hi".

Comment: `lower_bound` should never return null. (null isn't even an `iterator`.) If all keys in the `map` go before `mykey` (which is also true if the `map` is empty), then `lower_bound` will return `mymap.end()`, and, if the map is not empty, my statement will return an iterator to the last element in the map.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you actually test my answer, or is what you said just what you assume that would happen?

Comment: `@JSQuareD:` Yes. NULL means `mymap.end()`. I means it does not return a valid element. I tested the code. In my example above, `std::map<int, string> mymap; mymap[10] = "hi";`, then both `mymap.lower_bound(11)` and `mymap.lower_bound(11)--` return `mymap.end()`. `mymap.upper_bound(11)` also returns mymap.end(). This is different from the `lowerEntry()` of Java's TreeMap.

Comment: @John My apologies, I made a minor typo in the answer. A pre-increment should be used instead of a post-increment, otherwise the returned value will simply be the value of `lower_bound`.

Comment: Well, pre-*de*crement and post-*de*crement, actually.

Comment: `@JSQuareD` I got it. Thanks.